# Change background Color for group radio inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem** I have a form that the user fills out (basic things like your name, phone number, email, etc). It has a question that asks the user if you want your suggestion to remain anonymous and the user either selects yes or no.

The following image is what I am talking about:

[image]

If the user does not select either of the selections and submits the form, a alert box appears notifying the user to select one.

I am able to color a single radio selection red if the user has not selected either of them. I am able to color both radio selections red like the following:

[image]

And here is the function that checks whether or not either of those radio buttons have been selected:

```
myOption = -1;

for ( i=0; i < SubmitIdea.Anonymous.length; i++ ) {

    if ( SubmitIdea.Anonymous[i].checked ) {
        myOption = i;
    }
}

if ( myOption == -1 ) {

    alert( "Do you wish to remain anonymous?" );

    SubmitIdea.Anonymous[0].focus();
    SubmitIdea.Anonymous[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    SubmitIdea.Anonymous[1].focus();
    SubmitIdea.Anonymous[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";

    return false;

}
```

However, I would like the rectangular background border surrounding both the Yes and No radio selection, not individually. This rectangular border will only occur if neither radio selection has been choosen when the user has submitted their results.

The following is the html:

```
    <form name="SubmitIdea" method="POST" class="h"> 

  <table Border="0" align="center">
               <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                   <cfoutput>  
                   <tr>
                      <td  class="m">Name:&nbsp;</font></td>
                      <td nowrap="nowrap" class="r">
                      <input type="text" name="Name" value="" class="a" maxlength="32">
                      </td>
                      <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td  class="mm">Today's Date:&nbsp;</font></td>

                    <td class="mm">#TodaysDt#</td></tr>
                    </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td  class="mm">Department:&nbsp;</font></td>
                      <td nowrap="nowrap" class="r">
                      <input type="text" name="Department" value="" class="a" maxlength="32">
                      </td>
                      <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td  class="mm">Supervisor Name:&nbsp;</font></td>
                     <td nowrap="nowrap" class="r">  
                    <input type="text" name="Supervisor" value="" class="a" maxlength="32">
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td  class="mm">Email:&nbsp;</font></td>
                      <td nowrap="nowrap" class="r">
                      <input type="text" name="NomEmail" value="" class="a" maxlength="32" size="25">&nbsp;<br />
                      </td>
                      <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td  class="mm">Phone:&nbsp;</font></td>
                      <td nowrap="nowrap" class="r">
                      <input type="text" name="Phone" value="" class="a" maxlength="32">
                    </tr>
</table>
                <table border="0" width="500" align="center">
                <tr>
                <td class="c" align="center">
                  Your name will be shared and published along with your suggestion unless you want to remain anonymous. Do you wish to remain anonymous?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="Anonymous" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Yes</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="No" name="Anonymous">&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>No</strong>
                    </td>                    
                    </tr>

</table>
</cfoutput>

         <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="r"><strong>Please provide a brief summary of your idea:</strong></td>
        </tr>   
</table>
             <table border="0" align="center">
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                    </tr>


        <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
        <textarea name="reason" id="textarea1" cols="6" maxlength="500" class="c"
        style="background-color: transparent; color:##000000; font-size:14px;" 
        onFocus="clearTxt(this)" onkeydown="limitTxtArea(this); cntTxt(this, 500, 'cnt');" onkeyup="limitTxtArea(this); cntTxt(this, 500, 'cnt');"></textarea>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="cnt" style="color:##FF0000">500</span> character(s) remaining.<br /></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
</table>
       <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="r"><strong>I believe this suggestion will: (check all that apply)</strong></td>
        </tr>
</table>
      <table border="0" align="center">
       <tr>
                      <td  class="e"><input type="checkbox" name="Sugg1" value="Improve Productivity/Quality">Improve Productivity/Quality&nbsp;</font></td>
<td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                       <td  class="e"><input type="checkbox" name="Sugg2" value="Improve Process">Improve Process&nbsp;</font></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td  class="e"><input type="checkbox" name="Sugg3" value="Increase Revenue">Increase Revenue&nbsp;</font></td>
<td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                       <td  class="e"><input type="checkbox" name="Sugg4" value="Decrease Expenses/Costs">Decrease Expenses/Costs&nbsp;</font></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td  class="e"><input type="checkbox" name="Sugg5" value="Improve safety in the workplace">Improve safety in the workplace &nbsp;</font></td>
<td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                       <td  class="e"><input type="checkbox" name="Sugg6" value="Improve Customer Service">Improve Customer Service&nbsp;</font></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td  class="e"><input type="checkbox" name="Sugg7" value="Enhance employee satisfaction / corporate culture">Enhance employee satisfaction/<br>corporate culture&nbsp;</font></td>
<td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                       <td  class="e"><input type="checkbox" name="Sugg0" value="Other">Other&nbsp;<input type="text" name="OtherSuggest" value="" class="a" maxlength="32"></font></td>

                    </tr>
</table>

      <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="r"><strong>Possible challenges to implementation:</strong></td>
        </tr>
</table>

       <table border="0" align="center"> 
        <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
         <textarea name="reasontwo" id="textarea2" cols="6" maxlength="500" class="c" 
        style="background-color: transparent; color:##000000; font-size:14px;" 
        onFocus="clearTxtTwo(this)" onkeydown="limitTxtAreaTwo(this); cntTxtTwo(this, 500, 'cnttwo');" onkeyup="limitTxtAreaTwo(this); cntTxtTwo(this, 500, 'cnttwo');"></textarea>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="cnttwo" style="color:##FF0000">500</span> character(s) remaining.<br /></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
</table>
         <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="r"><strong>What metrics could be used to track results?</strong></td>
        </tr>
</table>   
             <table border="0" align="center">    
        <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
         <textarea name="reasonthree" id="textarea3" cols="6" maxlength="500" class="c" 
        style="background-color: transparent; color:##000000; font-size:14px;" 
        onFocus="clearTxtThree(this)" onkeydown="limitTxtAreaThree(this); cntTxtThree(this, 500, 'cntthree');" onkeyup="limitTxtAreaThree(this); cntTxtThree(this, 500, 'cntthree');"></textarea>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="cntthree" style="color:##FF0000">500</span> character(s) remaining.<br /><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>




                 <br />
            <table align="center">
                <TR>
                  <TD align="center"><input type="button" value=" Submit " onClick="SubmitMe()" name="SubmitIdeaBtn" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                     </td>   
                </tr>
            </table>




</form>
```

Thank You

**UPDATE**

The following is what I did:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   document.addEventListener("click", function(clickEvent) {
  if (clickEvent.target.id == 'check') {
    var anonymousInputs = document.getElementsByName('Anonymous');
    var anonymousContainer = document.getElementById('anonymousContainer');
    var anonymousSelected = Array.prototype.find.call(anonymousInputs,function(radioInput) {return radioInput.checked;});
    if (anonymousSelected) {
 anonymousContainer.className = '';
   } 
    else {
   if (anonymousContainer) {
     alert( "Do you wish to remain anonymous?" );
     anonymousContainer.className += 'borderedContainer';
   }
    }
  }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <table border="0" width="500" align="center">
<tr>
<td class="c" align="center">
<div>
  Your name will be shared and published along with your suggestion unless you want to remain anonymous. Do you wish to remain anonymous?&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="anonymousContainer"><input type="radio" name="Anonymous" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Yes</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="No" name="Anonymous">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>No</strong>
    </span>
</div>
  </td>                    
</tr>   
</table>

<table align="center">
    <TR>
      <TD align="center"><input id="check" type="button" value=" Submit " onClick="SubmitMe()" name="SubmitIdeaBtn" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
      </td>   
    </tr>
   </table>
```

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hungerstar I have updated my question. Thank You

Comment: Unnecessary logic when asking your question. Simplify it to the root of the problem, after your update it still has junk.

But here is a example of changing the look and feel of radio buttons.
http://jsbin.com/zequb/7/edit?html,css,output   (If that is what you are getting at)

Comment: @Mikes3ds Hello Mike, I see your example but that is not what I am looking for. As you can see above, the selection box's is highlighted red. I would like have a rectangular border surrounding both the selection boxes and the text next to them

Comment: Add a div with no border around the yes/no and text. (Add a border using javascript or jquery)  If you need guidance I can help coding it.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_border

Comment: @Mikes3ds I would need help. I have tried to use a div but forces the radio buttons on the next line which is not want I want. I have tried using a span but it doesnt work either

Comment: Your HTML is malformed (Meaning not properly closed tags) Please update. (This is not your problem but its best to keep it clean) See red->
https://jsfiddle.net/ygfcwrqu/

Comment: In case you need help cleaning it up https://infohound.net/tidy/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130648/discussion-between-mikes3ds-and-roberto-flores).

Answer (score 2):

You can put the radio buttons in a container (e.g. a [*span*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)) and then set the border on the container. See the example below, after clicking the button labeled *check*.

The snippet uses the [hex value for red](http://www.color-hex.com/color/ff0000) but feel free to adjust to a different value. Using 'red' as the value may produce varying results across browsers/Operating systems. For more information, refer to the [MDN color page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value).

The snippet also uses [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to determine if any of the radio inputs are checked.

#### Note:

I originally utilized [document.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for event delegation and to wait until the DOM was loaded but the OP is using IE 8 or earlier and had issues with that, so I removed that code.

```js
function checkAnonymousSelected(clickEvent) {
  var anonymousInputs = document.getElementsByName('Anonymous');
  var anonymousContainer = document.getElementById('anonymousContainer');
  var anonymousSelected = Array.prototype.find.call(anonymousInputs, function(radioInput) {
    return radioInput.checked;
  });
  if (anonymousSelected) {
    anonymousContainer.className = '';
  } else {
    if (anonymousContainer) {
      anonymousContainer.className += 'borderedContainer';
    }
  }
}
//support IE 8- for OP so do this instead of using document.attachEventListener 
//to wait until the DOM is ready and attach event listeners to the buttons...
document.getElementById('check').onclick = checkAnonymousSelected;
document.getElementById('anonymousYes').onclick = checkAnonymousSelected;
document.getElementById('anonymousNo').onclick = checkAnonymousSelected;
```

```css
.borderedContainer {
  border: 3px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Your name will be shared and published along with your suggestion unless you want to remain anonymous. Do you wish to remain anonymous?&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="anonymousContainer"><input type="radio" name="Anonymous" value="Yes" id="anonymousYes" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Yes</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="No" name="Anonymous" id="anonymousNo" >
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>No</strong>
    </span>
</div>
<button id="check">check</button>
```

Comment: I am able to do this without having a container. The problem I am having is to have a rectangular border on radio buttons, meaning surrounding the radio button, Yes, and etc

Comment: okay I updated the answer to add a border to a single container (with both radio buttons) instead of a background image, per your updated question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. The red rectangular should only appear if those selections have not appeared

Comment: Alright - I had left a comment there for you to add your logic but I have replaced that with some logic to determine if any of the radio buttons are selected.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to use what you did but apply to what I did but not getting it to work. I have also tried to use your code and add in the alert but nothing happens as well

Comment: Perhaps there is an error somewhere- have you looked in the browser console?

Comment: Says the following error: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' 
Employee_Ideas.cfm, line 90 character 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130649/discussion-between-sam-onela-and-roberto-flores).

Comment: Hello Sam, for some reason, I am blocked from the chat

Comment: Are you supporting/using IE 8 or earlier? If so, you will need to (conditionally) use `document.attachEvent` instead of `document.addEventListener` - see the section "Legacy Internet Explorer and attachEvent" on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Right I am but the function I was using with "myOption = -1;" works well and the alert appears on IE and in other browsers. However, it doesnt have the update that you did with your code and when I modify it with your code, it doesnt work

Comment: Okay I updated the example to not use the attachEventListener function. I haven't tested it because I am not at my computer but can test it later. You could add an `onclick="checkAnonymous()"` to the `<button>` instead of setting the onClick property in JavaScript but it is better to not put JavaScript in the HTML.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I have a question: How would I get the border to go away once the user selects a radio button?

Comment: You could add a click handler to the radio buttons to call the same function used to see if the border should be applied (or if it should be removed)

Comment: Would it be the following:
    else{
    if(document.getElementById('NO').checked) {
      
    }else if(document.getElementById('YES').checked) {
      
    }
    }

Comment: As long as the `SubmitMe` function just checks whether the border should be added or removed (like my `checkAnonymous` function)- it probably shouldn't submit the form unless you want it to...

Comment: and in the html the following:<span id="anonymousContainer"><input onClick="SubmitMe()" id="YES"type="radio" name="Anonymous" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Yes</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <input onClick="SubmitMe()" id="NO" type="radio" value="No" name="Anonymous">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>No</strong>
      </span>

Comment: Yea that should work, or see my updated code snippet